# Parsing last part of URL in Splunk

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

I've an URL like

`https://officedomain.com/CDs/ProductMarketingName/Product/Version/MartkingName_Product_Version.exe`

and wrote the following query in Splunk search

```
index=<Server> sourcetype=<type> 
| rex field=URL_Field "http(s)?://[^/]+/(?<EXE_NAME>[^/]+)
```

But it returns me "CDs" instead of "MartkingName_Product_Version.exe"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

there are more than one path before you get to the EXE_NAME, but your expression only says to look for one.

change:

```
[^/]+/
```

to:

```
([^/]+/)+
```

or:

```
([^/]+/)*
```

So that it matches as many paths as it needs to, then the last step being your EXE_NAME:

```
http(s)?://([^/]+/)+(?<EXE_NAME>[^/]+)
```

Or you could use:

```
http(s)?://.*/(?<EXE_NAME>[^/]+)
```

Comment: No it did not work, but what i did is
```
|eval Exe_Version=mvindex(split(URL,"/"),-1) 
```
which seems to work

Answer (score 0):

This [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/cjAJTi/1) will match the last part of the URL that ends with (case-insensitive) "exe", and that ends the string:

```
| rex field=URL_Field "\/(?<exename>[^\/]+[eExXeE]{3})$"
```

THe format is this: start with a front slash, then match everything that's *not* a front slash that ends with "exe","EXE", etc, and that is at the end of the string in question

As you mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73170217/parsing-last-part-of-url-in-splunk/73195821#comment129227697_73170428) to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73170428/4418), using `split()` can also be a good option (sometimes it's faster to break a URL with `split()` ... so long as you ***know*** which element in the multivalue field you need